# Windows 8.1 Update - infinite reboot loop: "We couldn't complete the updates. Undoing changes"

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I just installed Windows 8.1. Unfortunately I also ran the automatic updates which messed everything up with an infinite reboot loop:

```
We couldn't complete the updates. Undoing changes. Don't turn off your computer.
```

[Microsoft apparently has no solution](http://infoworld.com/article/2608238/microsoft-windows/microsoft-posts-tips-for-overcoming-windows-8-1-update-kb-2919355-errors.html). Maybe somebody here has? I tried to reboot into Safe Mode in order to manually uninstall the updates there:

http://denvycom.com/blog/windows-8-1-how-to-fix-updates-failed-undoing-changes-issue/

But I get:

```
An error has occurred. Not all updates were uninstalled.
```

Comment: Restore your system using a restore point.

Comment: [Reset Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058) and try it again.

Comment: share the folder C:\windows\logs\cbs. Here I can see why Windows can't install the update.

Comment: Try installing updates in groups of 10, starting with "security updates" first, reboot between each batch.